# Hadoop : Permission denied (publickey,password, keyboard-interactive)

Tags: hadoop, ssh, localhost, macos-catalina, hadoop3

While installing Hadoop I got many errors but this one just doesn't go. No matter what I do, it keeps popping again and again. As soon as I am starting Hadoop by the command `./start-all.sh`, I get the error:

> localhost: rajneeshsahai@localhost: Permission denied
>   (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive)

Error logs:

```
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: rajneeshsahai@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).

Starting datanodes
localhost: rajneeshsahai@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).

Starting secondary namenodes [MacBook-Air.local]
MacBook-Air.local: rajneeshsahai@macbook-air.local: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).

2020-05-29 18:42:06,106 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

Starting resourcemanager
resourcemanager is running as process 2937.  Stop it first.

Starting nodemanagers
localhost: rajneeshsahai@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
```

I already tried the following things:

1. `ssh-keygen -t rsa`

   `cat ~/.ssh/id-rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

   `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

   I think repeating this process has created multiple keys in my system.
2. `sudo passwd`
3. Configured `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

   (i) Changed `PermitRootLogin prohibit-password` to `PermitRootLogin yes`

   (ii) Changed `PasswordAuthentication no` to `PasswordAuthentication yes`

   I do have one doubt: Do I have to remove the hash tag (`#`) from the lines?

I am using macOS Catalina.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Hash (`#`) at the start of a line is a comment. So anything you modify on such line will have no effect. You need to uncomment it. You will also have to restart the `SSH` daemon. See this link: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-change-ssh-port-on-linux-or-unix-server/

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
$ chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: This works perfect for me on AWS CentOS Stream 8

Answer (score 0):

On Windows WSL2 Ubuntu container you have to restart the ssh service to make it available for Hadoop. You could try to run the Hadoop in a docker container. See https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hadoop.

In the Ubuntu 20.04 container each time before I start Hadoop I restart the ssh service.

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

For more details see the following tutorial https://dev.to/samujjwaal/hadoop-installation-on-windows-10-using-wsl-2ck1.